# .Net performance of short-circuiting operators for comparing a value type?

Tags: c#, .net, optimization, conditional-statements, short-circuiting

If I am comparing two known value types, will I get better performance from the `|` or `||` operator in c#?

My particular use case is a `bool` member in the class indicating stale data, being activated by a loop method like this:

```
private bool _stale;
private HashSet<Foo> _foos;
```

Then another method loops and possibly activates this flag

```
foreach (var foo in foos)
{
    _stale = _foos.Add(foo) | _stale;

    //Or is the following line better?
    //_stale = _foos.Add(foo) || _stale; 
}
```

I suppose I'm asking if the overhead of the short-circuiting operator is enough that I wouldn't use it for checking against an already assigned value type...

Comment: Write the code both ways. Measure the perf. How else could you know which of two things is faster?

Comment: @EricLippert you may be one of the few people who might know *without* building the tests...

Comment: I assure you that is not true; if I've learned one thing about performance analysis it is that guessing which of two things is faster is pointless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use the [Or Assignment operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5f1zzaw.aspx):

```
_stale |= added;
```

Or:

```
_stale |= _foos.Add(foo);
```

This operator is specifically designed for this purpose, which makes the intent clear (and will most likely be the best in terms of performance, as it's specifically designed for this purpose).

As for the actual performance, this level of micro-optimization is typically almost impossible to measure as any difference in performance is going to be so much smaller than the difference in your operations (the `HashSet<T>.Add` call) that clarity of code is far more important.  You could build a test to measure this, but it is incredibly unlikely to be reliably different enough in terms of performance to matter.

Comment: The msdn isn't clear to me. Is the `.Add()` guaranteed to be executed?

Comment: @Matthew It will execute every time.

Comment: I know it's a micro optimization... but I can do it "optimally" without sacrificing clarity and without much effort then why not?

Comment: @Matthew Well, the sacrificing clarity is the key here - in this case, I think my option here is the most clear version, which is why I prefer it ;)

Comment: I completely agree, +1 ... I had never used this operator before.

Comment: @Matthew: The non-existent `||=` operator would not be guaranteed to execute `_.Add()`.  `|=` is comparable to `|`, which does not short-circuit.